# pdshare package of R

Tags: r, time-series, var, price

I have a question regarding [pdshare](https://rdrr.io/rforge/ifrogs/man/pdshare.html) package of R. In the [source code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/ifrogs/src/R/pdshare.R) the lines:

```
beta.ort <- as.vector(c(-cointest@V[2,1], cointest@V[1,1]))
alpha.ort <- as.vector(c(-cointest@W[2,1], cointest@W[1,1]))
```

The authors extract the `alpha` and `beta` vectors of VECM. I am unable to understand why a negative sign is placed before  `-cointest@V[2,1]` and `-cointest@W[2,1]`

Is someone aware of this?